# ios SQLite not working in device, works in simulator

Tags: ios, sql, iphone, ios7, sqlite

I am using below code ..in some statement which works fine with the Simulator but does not work with the device..it gets fails in the IF statement but works fine with the simulator..
what can be the issue .. please help

DB PAth

```
-(void) openDB {
NSString *databaseFilename = @"A.db";
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseFilename];
NSLog(@"file address %@",databasePath);
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

[fileManager removeItemAtPath:databasePath error:nil];


//copying
NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseFilename];
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];

if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &db) != SQLITE_OK) {
    sqlite3_close(db);
    NSAssert(0, @"Database failed to open.");
}
}
```

and code is

```
sqlite3_stmt *statement;

        NSString *sql;

       sql=@"INSERT into db values(?,?)";


        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db1, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK){


            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [A.text UTF8String], -1, NULL);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [B_text.text UTF8String], -1, NULL);



            sqlite3_step(statement);


            sqlite3_finalize(statement);


     }
```

Comment: What is your DB PATH?

Comment: You need to define your database path in Documents Directory ..

Comment: @rajesh please check Db path

Comment: @ParvendraSingh I have defined that.. updated code

Comment: Execution gets in to         if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db1, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK){
} condition? You are able to debug it?

Comment: no it gets failed here on device...but works fine into it ...for simulator

Comment: Did you check your database static instance ? IS it pointing to reference or nil?

Comment: your db1 is your database static instance...

Comment: not sure how to check it but this is giving me some 0x16d22870 value

Comment: i think you are ignoring character case. In simulator that will work fine but for device you need to give exact name as of original name...